# How can I destroy stream from a session?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, opentok

I am using opentok app for multi-call conference video call in the web application, Facing a problem while invited person (third participant) has ended the call total session has been ended.

Would like to hear a solution for invited person (third participant) has ended the call then only that person should be disconnected the session without disturbing the running session for the other two participants.

Comment: Can you copy/paste your code?  How is the third participant ending the call?  Calling `session.disconnect()` should not affect the session for the remaining two parties.

Comment: What hapnes here 3rd participant end the call complete session will destroy, but i want to destroy the 3 rd participant stream only (i am using session.dissconnect() and session.streamDestroy() also complete session destroyed ) can u pls help how to destroy the session with out distubing the session ? this is very urgent pls rly me (my mail id -sivajiyerra.ys@gmail.com )

Comment: I need to see the code to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your signaling server architecture, I imagine you would emit an "offer/answer" type signaling to the signaling server when you are initiating the peer connections. Sending a custom "bye" signaling along with the user id to the signaling server and broadcast the signaling to other peers. After the "bye" signaling has been received by the other peers, close the peer connection according to the userid that came with the signal and remove the video stream for the full closure.